# New to Cider making

Tags: fermentation

I made about 8 litres of cider 2 weeks ago and put it in a 30 litre fermentation bin which meant that there is a lot of air still in the bin. I have now learnt that is not ideal. Is there anything I can do. Should I leave it or move it to demijohns.
Any advise welcome
Darren

Answer (score 3):

For primary fermentation the extra headspace won't be a tremendous issue as the fermentation will fill the rest of the chamber with CO2. Cider can oxidize, however in my experienced the off-flavors aren't as pronounced as in a beer.

Once primary fermentation is over, you may want to rack it into a secondary container to condition. If you choose to do that- you will want to reduce the amount of headspace as much as possible during that time.